# Correctly setting up JTA Transaction Manager in Tomcat Server with Atomikos

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-transactions

How would I setup container-managed datasources and embedded Active MQ resources to `JTATransactionManager` for global Transactions?

I am using Tomcat 6 and installed Atomikos in it to support JTA. I use Hibernate for ORM. Here is my configuration:

```xml
<bean id="AtomikosTransactionManager"  
      class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"  
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close"> 
   <!--  when close is called, should we force  
         transactions to terminate or not?  --> 
   <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="AtomikosUserTransaction"  
   class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">      
   <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" /> 
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/EDITSOLUTIONS"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources"/>
    <list>
        <value>../../src/editsolutions.hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </list>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="failover://tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover://tcp://localhost:61616"/>
</bean>

<bean name="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="AtomikosTransactionManager" /> 
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="AtomikosUserTransaction" />
</bean>
```

Spring documentation says that JTA Transaction Manager need not be told about resources. That's what I have done.

#### I have the following outstanding questions:

1. I am not sure whether `Atomikos` is integrated properly or not?
2. Is it OK to get the datasource from `<jee:jndi-lookup>`?
3. Is Hiberante configuration correct with respect to `JTATransactionManager`?
4. As it is embedded in JVM not managed by container, would JTATransactionManager be able to recognize ActimeMQ ?

Comment: if get the datasource  from <jee:jndi-lookup> ,how to configure the jta ? The answer blow is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this very useful link: **http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration**

Remember to configure the datasource in this way:

```
<bean id="dataSourceA" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"  init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <qualifier value="jmsRecoveryDatabaseSchema"/> 
    <property name="uniqueResourceName"><value>XADS1</value></property> 
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName"> 
        <value>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</value> 
    </property> 
    <property name="xaProperties"> 
        <props> 
            <prop key="URL">${jdbc.url}</prop> 
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop> 
           <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop> 
        </props> 
    </property> 
    <property name="poolSize"><value>1</value></property>
    <property name="testQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
</bean>
```

I hope it helps!